# jQuery each() not executing on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

i've got a each() function which should execute on document.ready() but it doesn't. When i put the each() in a click.function() it works!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.addClassesToButtons();
});

jQuery.addClassesToButtons = (function(){
    jQuery('#acf_365 > div.inside > div.acf-tab-wrap > ul > li').each(function(i){
       jQuery(this).addClass( 'abstract-button-' + (i+1) );
    });
});
```

Why is my each function not executed on document ready but inside a click function it works?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Is addClassesToButtons() executed on document.ready() or not at all?

Comment: add a `console.log(jQuery('#acf_365 > div.inside > div.acf-tab-wrap > ul > li'));` before `.each()` to know if the function works and if the selector find the element. I create a fiddle and all works http://jsfiddle.net/c380qakn/ ...